# unable to do post call with Rest Client of firefox

Tags: java, google-chrome, rest, firefox-addon

I am unable to do post call with help rest client of the firefox, but i am able do with advance rest client of the chrome. Since we have restricatin with chrome in other system. This is like to do any setting. I am done with content-type: application/json and it is blank post call. It is working fine with http call but there is problem with https call only

Comment: I am not getting any reponse in the firefox rest client

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer for my issue,The problem is with self signed certificate from the server side which firefox wont do but the chrome does the thing for us. so i enter the url in the browser and hitted it and added exception to it and what it works....!!!! like charm

Answer (score 0):

Note that, when you are going for POST it is not just URL input, you need to form the inputs on POST object and send it to server.